# Linux boot freezes at WPA supplicant

Tags: fedora, boot, laptop, freeze, wpa-supplicant

When booting my laptop, which is running Fedora 30 on kernal 5.2.7, it freezes when it gets to WPA supplicant saying:

> [  OK  ]  Started WPA supplicant

But doesn't proceed any further. If anyone has a solution to this please let me know.

Comment: It looks to me that it’s freezing *after* WPA supplicant.

Comment: Maybe, sometimes another message will come after to do with the ipv6. Any ideas of a solution?

Comment: My only thought is to figure out what’s starting after WPA supplicant, and disable it in the boot process. You can do that by booting into a live CD and mounting your root filesystem.

Comment: I have this issue with Fedora every time I upgrade the kernel. My issue is with the video driver. I need to boot into the terminal, disable the `nouveau` driver, and manually re-install the correct driver for my video card. If this is your issue, these links may help: * [Boot in Terminal Mode](https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23521/boot-in-terminal-mode/) * [How to install the NVIDIA drivers on Fedora 32](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-fedora-32)